# I want to execute setInterval only once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Classes are randomly added to buttons for each div group. When the user clicks the button, the class is added to the clicked button, and after a few seconds, it should be randomized again.

.parents > li > div

There is a sweeper per group. A random class is inserted into the button only when the slide is active. When the user clicks the button, we need to provide a clearInterval and restart setRandomPlay after a few seconds.

**The setInterval runs continuously whenever the button is clicked. How can I only run it once?**

```
$(".parents  > li > div").each(function(idx, item) {
    var interval = setInterval(setRandomPlay ,2500);
    function setRandomPlay() {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(item).find('.swiper-slide-active button').length);
        $(item).find('.swiper-slide-active button').removeClass('on');
        $(item).find('.swiper-slide-active button').removeClass().eq(random).addClass('on');
    }
    $(item).find('.swiper-slide-active button').on('click', function(e){
        $(item).find('.swiper-slide-active button').removeClass("on");
        clearInterval(interval);
        if ($(this).hasClass("on")) {
            $(this).removeClass("on");
        } else {
            $(this).find('.swiper-slide-active button').removeClass("on");
            $(this).addClass("on");
        }
        setInterval(setRandomPlay ,2500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) is to run a function **every** ms.

If you want to run a function **once** after ms, then use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) instead.

Comment: setInterval(setRandomPlay ,2500); -> setTimeout(interval, 2500); 
I fixed it but it doesn't seem to work